# Using 'this' in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me with this, please?

This is my html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="vacation" data-price="339.99">
    <h3>British vacation</h3>
    <p>£339.99 per ticket</p>
    <p>Tickets: 
    <input type="number" class="quantity" value='1'>
    <p/>
  </div>
  <p>Total price £: <span class="total">399.99</span></p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="vacation" data-price="449.99">
    <h3>Spanish vacation</h3>
    <p>£449.99 per ticket</p>
    <p>Tickets: 
    <input type="number" class="quantity" value='1'>
    <p/>
  </div>
  <p>Total price £: <span class="total">449.99</span></p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="vacation" data-price="559.99">
    <h3>Italian vacation</h3>
    <p>£559.99 per ticket</p>
    <p>Tickets: 
    <input type="number" class="quantity" value='1'>
    <p/>
  </div>
  <p>Total price £: <span class="total">559.99</span></p>
</div>
```

And jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.vacation').on('keyup', '.quantity', function() {

  var price = +$(this).closest('.vacation').data('price');
  var quantity = +$(this).closest('.quantity').val();
  var totalPrice = (price * quantity).toFixed(2);
  $('.total').text(totalPrice);

 });
});
```

The problem is that when I'm calculating a price for one of the vacation options I've got all the total prices updated.
I've tried with  :

```
$(this).closest('.total').text(totalPrice);
```

And it's not working.

Please check it on **[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/duxuyeb/edit?html,js,output)**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you select all `.total` elements and set the `text()` on them. Instead you could use `closest()` to get the nearest parent `.wrapper` element from the `.quantity` which raised the event and `find()` all the required elements within that, like this:

```
$('.vacation').on('keyup input', '.quantity', function() {
    var $wrapper = $(this).closest('.wrapper');
    var price = parseFloat($wrapper.find('.vacation').data('price'));
    var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $wrapper.find('.total').text((price * quantity).toFixed(2));
});
```

Also note that I hooked to the `input` event to cover users who click the up/down arrows on the `number` input.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

Instead of

```
$('.total').text(totalPrice);
```

Go for

```
$(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.total').text(totalPrice);
```

Here we are going up in DOM structure till `.wrapper` and then looking for associated `.total` element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from the following line :

```
$('.total').text(totalPrice);
```

It will change the text of all elements with class `.total`. It should be :

```
$(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.total').text(totalPrice);
//OR
$(this).parents('.wrapper').find('.total').text(totalPrice);
```

So the selector will go up to the parent `.wrapper` then search for the `.total` element related with edited `.quantity`.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.vacation').on('keyup', '.quantity', function() {

    var price = +$(this).closest('.vacation').data('price');
    var quantity = +$(this).closest('.quantity').val();
    var totalPrice = (price * quantity).toFixed(2);
    
    $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.total').text(totalPrice);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="vacation" data-price="339.99">
    <h3>British vacation</h3>
    <p>£339.99 per ticket</p>
    <p>Tickets: 
      <input type="number" class="quantity" value='1'>
    <p/>
  </div>
  <p>Total price £: <span class="total">399.99</span></p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="vacation" data-price="449.99">
    <h3>Spanish vacation</h3>
    <p>£449.99 per ticket</p>
    <p>Tickets: 
      <input type="number" class="quantity" value='1'>
    <p/>
  </div>
  <p>Total price £: <span class="total">449.99</span></p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="vacation" data-price="559.99">
    <h3>Italian vacation</h3>
    <p>£559.99 per ticket</p>
    <p>Tickets: 
      <input type="number" class="quantity" value='1'>
    <p/>
  </div>
  <p>Total price £: <span class="total">559.99</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.vacation').on('input', '.quantity', function() {
     
  var price = +$(this).parent().parent().data('price');
  var quantity = +$(this).val();
  var totalPrice = (price * quantity).toFixed(2);
  $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.total').text(totalPrice);
   
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="vacation" data-price="339.99">
     <h3>British vacation</h3>
     <p>£339.99 per ticket</p>
     <p>Tickets: 
     <input type="number" class="quantity" value='1'>
     <p/>
   </div>
   <p>Total price £: <span class="total">399.99</span></p>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="vacation" data-price="449.99">
     <h3>Spanish vacation</h3>
     <p>£449.99 per ticket</p>
     <p>Tickets: 
     <input type="number" class="quantity" value='1'>
     <p/>
   </div>
   <p>Total price £: <span class="total">449.99</span></p>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="vacation" data-price="559.99">
     <h3>Italian vacation</h3>
     <p>£559.99 per ticket</p>
     <p>Tickets: 
     <input type="number" class="quantity" value='1'>
     <p/>
   </div>
   <p>Total price £: <span class="total">559.99</span></p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```